# Force of permanent magnet on an iron weight

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is there a way to calculate the magnetic pull force exerted by a cylindrical permanent magnet on a piece of iron, given the distance, shape, and properties of both the magnet and the iron? I found an equation to calculate the magnetic flux density (https://www.supermagnete.de/eng/faq/How-do-you-calculate-the-magnetic-flux-density), but I wasn't sure how to calculate or approximate the magnetic pull force. I also found the formula for a force between two nearby magnetized surfaces $F = \frac {B^2A}{2\mu_0}$, but I wasn't sure if it was applicable. I would appreciate any direction on this.

Comment: How would you describe the properties of  the magnet ? usually it is the weight it can just hold in contact?

Comment: @trula I was thinking of properties like remanence, dimensions, and reversible temperature coefficients as I've seen them in many relevant equations, but I'm not sure about all the relevant parameters. Is there an equation to calculate the maximum weight it can hold, or is it experimentally found?

Comment: In a system consisting of a magnet and iron, the magnetization on the magnet side can be approximated by a constant magnetization, but the state of magnetization on the iron side changes under the influence of the surrounding magnetic field, so we must inevitably rely on numerical calculations such as the finite element method. Once the state of magnetic field are obtained by numerical calculation, the force is calculated from Maxwell's stress tensor, for example. It would be nice if there were a simple formula, but I am not aware of any such formula.

Comment: @HEMMI Thank you for your help! For a simple formula, what about the formula for the force between an electromagnet and an armature $F = \frac {Ni\mu_0A}{2g^2}$ from http://depts.washington.edu/mictech/optics/sensors/week2.pdf? Can it be applicable to a permanent magnet and an iron piece if the permanent magnet is modelled as a solenoid?

Comment: @ggggggggg, the 2nd article you quote seems interesting and practically useful.  If we substitute $Ni=ML$ ($M$ is the magnetisation of the magnet in units of A/m and $L$ is the vertical length of the magnet), we probably get the formula you want. But the formula is approximate,  we need to multiply it by some numerical factor to compensate for the real geometry. I would find the correction value by experiment.

Comment: @ggggg usually you buy a permanent magnet it gives you the weight it can just hold in contact. it diminishes with about d^3 for short distances d.